# Small n - dimension reduction and regression

Tags: pca, lasso, small-sample

I am trying to develop a *valid* method for modeling some biological data. I do not need it to be predictive necessarily, but I want to be able to show relationships and determine which set (of many) has a strong relationship.

In general, my data has n = 18 with x ~ 17 (though this varies) collinear variables. Based on what I know about the biology, there should be some sort of linear combination of variables that I can use to predict outcomes. I have been reading as much as I can, including a lot of Frank Harrell's work, but I am having a hard time determining if my approach is valid (or if there is something better that I can do).

Process:

- Variable reduction via PCA. I can get to 90% of variation explained on 6 PCs, and usually hit ~ 60% on just two
- Use best subsets regression with the PCs to build linear models. Pick the "best" one using AIC or BIC criteria. Due to the small n, I am trying to stick to 3 or fewer components in the model.
- Present adjusted R2, p-value (?), AIC/BIC, and residual standard error

I also have considered using rms::validate and presenting the index.corrected R-square and/or MSE.

Is there something that I'm missing here? Is there something you (as a reader of this hypothetical study) would like to see presented that I am leaving out? This is aimed at biologists, not statisticians, so the stats need to be sound, but not revolutionary.

Due to small sample size, I have stayed away from LASSO due to not wanting to sacrifice data for parameter tuning. I know nothing of Bayesian methods other than the simple things I have tried to teach myself, but I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: First thing I'd do is ask myself whether I can reduce dimensionality based on subject matter grounds, like for example summarising a number of closely related variables by one wisely defined index that measures more or less the same thing. Obviously this depends on the meaning of your variables, of which I have no idea.

Comment: Unrelated to my first comment, an approach that you may have a look at is partial least squares. This may work better than PCA in the sense that it incorporates the information of the $y$ in the dimension reduction.

Comment: I did some PLS work, but wasn't sure of the best method for validity (kfold CV, LOOCV?) with small sample size.  I can (kind of) bin the variables based on biological information, but still end up with ~5 categories so it's not much better than PCs

Comment: Validation is hard with n=18 regardless of what you do. Not sure whether bootstrap can squeeze more out of the data than CV. The problem with PCA is that variance (PCA's objective) may be unrelated to predictability, and biological knowledge (as well as PLS) may be better in that respect.

Comment: I was initially leaning on PLS, but I was having a hard time judging the validity (or stability) of the approach. Any CV tips to help with that?